# How do I include this php library inside my existing PHP code?

Tags: php, drupal

I am trying to add a form inside my php page that validates the fiscal code for Italians. Basically just an input field validates the values being entered by the user.

I found [this](https://github.com/DavidePastore/codice-fiscale/blob/master/src/CodiceFiscale/Validator.php#L1) repo on github and it's exactly what I'm looking for. I am just not sure how I can implement this inside my existing website? I am planning to just insert it on my current php page. My site is running on Drupal 7, if that helps.

Most of my function starts this way:

```
function VerifyTable(&$values, &$errors)
{}
```

I don't entirely understand PHP, have a little to none knowledge of it. Just trying to experiment on stuff at the moment to learn but I can't seem to understand how to make that source code work on my code... I don't know how I should be adding those private and public classes..

I hope someone could enlighten me.

Comment: It seems that Drupal uses Composer to manage its dependencies so all you need to do is run `composer require davidepastore/codice-fiscale` from the command line.

Comment: @jeroen so all I have to do is to install composer, run it and then I can just use it from there? Sorry, I am still confused :(